# Creating Data Validation List using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a drop down menu using macros. In the Internet I found the code below which works perfectly. The only issue is that I need to get the contents on the drop down menu (i.e. `=$B$1:$B$6`) from a specific sheet (let's say `Sheet2`). Tried several attempts to direct to a specific sheet, but unfortunately non of them worked.

```
With Range("A1:A100")
    With .Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$1:$B$6"
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are specifying that you want the validation to come from `Sheet2`, then you need to add that to your formula `Formula1:="=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$6"`.

I would also add a `.delete` to clear any prior validation first - else you will likely encounter an error if you had any validation from prior attempts.

```
With Range("A1:A100")
    With .Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$6"
    End With
End With
```

Finally, you should really consider qualifying your `Range("A1:A100")` with your worksheet, so something like

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100")
```

And better yet, consider qualifying the above with your workbook as well.